# Destroy a button that was added programatically multiple times on its click

Tags: java, android

The title may sound confusing I know, I 'm adding a view everytime I click on a button, composed by a textview and a button. I'm setting every added view an ID with simply `view.setID(++i)` and every added button (inside the views) an ID simply with `button.setID(++n)`, `n` starting at 1000, since I won't have more than 1000 added views.

Here's what I got:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    GridLayout gridLayout;
    static int i;
    static int n = 1000;
    private Button theButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gamehistory);
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {

                theButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                TextView theText = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                theText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

                LinearLayout theLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                theLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                theLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8BAAC3"));
                theLayout.setId(++i);
                theButton.setId(++n);
                theButton.setText(theButton.getId() + "");
                theText.setText(theLayout.getId() + "");
                theLayout.addView(theButton);
                theLayout.addView(theText);
                gridLayout.addView(theLayout);
                GridLayout.LayoutParams lp = (GridLayout.LayoutParams) theLayout.getLayoutParams();
                lp.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
            }
        });
```

What I need is when I click on a button that was created, the correspondent view is destroyed, and the next views take one step back feeling the gap in the parent which is a GridLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this  where you are adding views to `GridLayout` -

```
theLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
           gridLayout.removeView(theLayout);
      }
});
theButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         gridLayout.removeView(theLayout);
      }
});
```

For this , you need to make `theLayout` final

```
final LinearLayout theLayout = new LinearLayout(LauncherActivity.this);
```

Comment: I had no idea it was this simple and obvious... Thanks a lot!

Comment: One quesiton, why does it need to be declered final?

Comment: Yes I did and it does, why is it so? why does it have to be final?

Comment: I'm going to implement this in a way, that when I click each button, it acctually opens a dialog, and inside that dialog there will be a button, by clicking in that button (inside the dialog) I want to destroy the view that opened it, so i have to access the view through a dialogFragment, how do I do that if I need to declare the view final inside the method that I create it, and use it?

Comment: Post a different question for this.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method would be.

```
View v = gridLayout.findViewById(<some id>);
gridLayout.removeView(v);
```

However it seems like you may want to consider using a [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html). You can add/remove items from the Adapter and the views will be updated for you.

**EDIT**

When using A RecyclerView you have to specify two essential components.

1. RecyclerAdapter - This converts data into views (rows, cards, cells, ect.)
2. LayoutManger - Most common are [LinearLayoutManger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html) and [GridLayoutManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html) which define how the views from the adapter are presented out in relation to one another, and handle scrolling.

There are a few more option additions you can can use if needed.

- [ItemDecoration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html) - define backgrounds, or overlays for cells. (E.G. draw a gray background for every other view in a list)
- [ItemTouchHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html) - does most of the heavy lifting for swipe (e.g. swipe to delete) and drag (e.g. drag to re-arrange) operations.

I would highly suggest getting familiar with the RecyclerView it should be your goto component when you need to display a list of items on the screen.

Comment: The gridLayout I'm using has 3 collumns, how can I create the same layout but with a recyclerView instead?

Comment: I updated my answer to give a bit more detail. Basically you want to use the GridLayoutManger and define the number of columns.

Comment: Alright I will get into it and probabily end up using it, but can you explain why is a RecyclerView a better practice than a GridLayout please?

Comment: A GridLayout is best for static content (screen has a grid of 6 buttons). A RecyclerView is best for dynamic content (screen shows x items in a grid).

Comment: I've been trying to turn it into a RecyclerView but I've been struggling, I've created [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499691/android-recyclerview-behaving-as-a-gridlayout) in case you can help!