# Android: RecyclerView behaving as a GridLayout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need to create a RecyclerView with 3 columns, with a button that when clicked, a custom view is added into the RecyclerView. And when I click in a view, it gets deleted. for example: I added 5 views, if I click on number 3, number 3 gets destroyed, and number 4 e 5 take one step back. I've created this in a GridLayout, but I want it to be in a RecyclerView, I'm aware that I need an Adapter, a Viewholder and a LayoutManager. So how is this done?

This is how it looked with a GridLayout:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    GridLayout gridLayout;
    static int i;
    static int n = 1000;
    private Button theButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gamehistory);
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {

                theButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                TextView theText = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                theText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                final LinearLayout theLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);

                theLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                theLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8BAAC3"));
                theLayout.setId(++i);
                theButton.setId(++n);
                theButton.setText(theButton.getId() + "");
                theText.setText(theLayout.getId() + "");
                theLayout.addView(theButton);
                theLayout.addView(theText);
                gridLayout.addView(theLayout);
                GridLayout.LayoutParams lp = (GridLayout.LayoutParams) theLayout.getLayoutParams();
                lp.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

                theButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        gridLayout.removeView(theLayout);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Regarding my attempts with a RecyclerView I've tried a [guide in a blog](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html) but it didn't work.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Regarding my attempts with a RecyclerView I've tried a guide in a blog but it didn't work.


  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you should post what code you attempted with the RecyclerView (not the code with the GridView). That being said here are some examples to get you going in the right direction.

**SAMPLE ATIVITY**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int NUMBER_COLUMNS = 3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, NUMBER_COLUMNS));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SampleItemDecoration());
        final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Items can be added to adapter from any part of code
        adapter.addItem("Static Item A");
        adapter.addItem("Static Item B");


        findViewById(R.id.button_add_item).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int i;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.addItem("Dynamic Item " + i++);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**SAMPLE ADAPTER**

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addItem(String name) {
        items.add(name);
        notifyItemInserted(items.size() - 1);
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        items.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_button, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setButtonName(items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private Button button;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grid_button);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


        public void setButtonName(String buttonName) {
            button.setText(buttonName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            removeItem(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

**SAMPLE DECORATOR**

```
class SampleItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = parent.getLayoutManager();
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View view = parent.getChildAt(i);
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#8BAAC3"));
            if (parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view) == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                continue;
            }

            // Compute bounds of cell in layout
            Rect bounds = new Rect(
                    layoutManager.getDecoratedLeft(view),
                    layoutManager.getDecoratedTop(view),
                    layoutManager.getDecoratedRight(view),
                    layoutManager.getDecoratedBottom(view)
            );

            // Add space between cell backgrounds
            bounds.inset(2, 2);

            c.drawRect(bounds, paint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        outRect.set(10, 10, 10, 10); // Specify spacing between items in grid
    }
}
```

Comment: I posed the link to the guide with the code I had tried! Thanks a lot, it works perfectly! :D

Comment: But you did not post the code you tried ;). Glad I was able to help.

Comment: One question, why does `adapter.addItem("Static Item A")` add a new button, and that string goes into the button text?

Comment: Why? Because a RecyclerView displays the items in the RecyclerAdapter and you added an item to the RecyclerAdapter. If you mean how? That is a bit outside the scope of this question.

Comment: What I meant was why does that string go right into the button's text?

Comment: Ahh. The ViewHolder is setting the buttonText to the String value. Because the view can be reused (when you scroll for example). The view holder is responsible for updating the view to match the current data.